Cisco IR829 , Cellular is not getting IP address
hello I have a problem with my current router and with this model Ir829 i always have problem to get ip address by cellular, the sim card seems to work good with other device, and i have tested severals configurations with no results. this is my current config
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 3952 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 00:03:22 UTC Tue May 7 2024
!
version 15.7
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname IR800
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
!
no aaa new-model
service-module wlan-ap 0 bootimage autonomous
!
ignition off-timer 900
!
ignition undervoltage threshold 11
!
no ignition enable
!
!
!
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
chat-script lte "" "AT!CALL" TIMEOUT 20 "OK"
!
!
license udi pid IR829-2LTE-EA-BK9 sn FTX2223Z023
!
!
vtp mode transparent
!
redundancy

!
!
!
!
!
controller Cellular 0
 lte sim data-profile 1 attach-profile 1
 lte modem link-recovery rssi onset-threshold -110
 lte modem link-recovery monitor-timer 20
 lte modem link-recovery wait-timer 10
 lte modem link-recovery debounce-count 6
!
controller Cellular 1
 lte sim data-profile 1 attach-profile 1
 no lte gps enable
 lte modem link-recovery rssi onset-threshold -110
 lte modem link-recovery monitor-timer 20
 lte modem link-recovery wait-timer 10
 lte modem link-recovery debounce-count 6
!
vlan 11
 name 10.202.241.0/24_DATA
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet1
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet2
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet3
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet4
 no ip address
!
interface Wlan-GigabitEthernet0
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet5
 no ip address
 shutdown
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Cellular0/0
 ip address negotiated
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 encapsulation slip
 load-interval 30
 dialer in-band
 dialer string lte
 dialer-group 1
 no peer default ip address
 async mode interactive
 routing dynamic
!
interface Cellular1/0
 ip address negotiated
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 encapsulation slip
 load-interval 30
 dialer in-band
 dialer string lte
 dialer-group 1
 no peer default ip address
 async mode interactive
 routing dynamic
!
interface Cellular0/1
 ip address negotiated
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 encapsulation slip
 load-interval 30
 dialer in-band
 dialer string lte
 dialer-group 1
 no peer default ip address
 async mode interactive
 routing dynamic
!
interface Cellular1/1
 no ip address
 encapsulation slip
!
interface wlan-ap0
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 ip address dhcp
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
!
interface Async0
 no ip address
 encapsulation scada
!
interface Async1
 no ip address
 encapsulation scada
!
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
ip nat inside source list 2 interface Cellular0/0 overload
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Cellular0/0
!
dialer-list 1 protocol ip permit
ipv6 ioam timestamp
!
!
access-list 1 permit any
access-list 2 permit any
!
control-plane
!
!
!
 vstack
!
line con 0
 stopbits 1
line 1 2
 stopbits 1
line 3
 script dialer lte
 no exec
 transport preferred lat pad telnet rlogin lapb-ta mop udptn v120 ssh
 transport output lat pad telnet rlogin lapb-ta mop udptn v120 ssh
line 4
 no activation-character
 no exec
 transport preferred none
 transport input all
 transport output lat pad telnet rlogin lapb-ta mop udptn v120 ssh
line 8
 no exec
 transport preferred lat pad telnet rlogin lapb-ta mop udptn v120 ssh
 transport output lat pad telnet rlogin lapb-ta mop udptn v120 ssh
line 9
 script dialer lte
 no exec
 transport preferred lat pad telnet rlogin lapb-ta mop udptn v120 ssh
 transport output lat pad telnet rlogin lapb-ta mop udptn v120 ssh
line 15
 no exec
 transport preferred lat pad telnet rlogin lapb-ta mop udptn v120 ssh
 transport output lat pad telnet rlogin lapb-ta mop udptn v120 ssh
line 1/3 1/6
 transport preferred none
 transport output none
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 login
 transport input none
!
no scheduler max-task-time
no iox hdm-enable
iox client enable interface GigabitEthernet5
no iox recovery-enable
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
end


what is the problem specifically?
